# DC hipot leakage current

Tags: dc, high-voltage, testing, dielectric, hipot

I noticed that when testing hipot in DC I always get leakage current, but not during AC hipot testing. Do you have any ideas about this? My hipot tester is Quadtech Sentry 500VA. I’m testing a dielectric made of PEEK and alumina.

Comment: Strange. I have had the opposite happen to me. Can you share a schematic or block diagram?

Comment: What is your equipment and what do you test?

Comment: My hipot tester is Quadtech Sentry 500VA. I am testing a dielectric made of PEEK and alumina.

Comment: Oh, PEEK, my favorite plastic. Interesting. Any dielectric properties would not change much between DC and 50 Hz. Do you have no active parts at all?

Comment: @YbxNop Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: Is the leakage rising over time or instant visible?

Comment: I suggest you grab a piece of polyimide and verify the workings of your device and setup.  Definitely makes me wonder if there was a flaw in your material.  Could someone have burned the PEEK in part of your manufacturing process or maybe the quality of alumina was not quite right to begin with?

Comment: The PEEK is printed on top of aluminum substrate. The hipot connection is between the aluminum and the electrode (made of graphite) on top of the PEEK. I used another hipot equipment and showed me the same result. The leakage current is rising as I increased the voltage but for AC only. I tested an 18 awg wire and got the same result as well. So there is an explanation on why I got leakage current on AC and not with DC.

Comment: Sorry guys what I meant is that in AC I have leakage current but not in DC.